# Error correction : Although their visas will expire in September they can have them extended for six months

Tags: present-tense, future-tense, exam-questions

> Although their visas will expire in September they can have them extended for six months.

My book says that I need to remove **will** from the above given sentence because for fixed events of future we use Simple Present tense E.g. We leave for London tomorrow.
This may be right that we **can** use simple present tense for such future events but is using future tense incorrect ?

Comment: I would say you're right and you could just as well say "we will leave for London tomorrow". So let's see what the experts will say. This will be interesting.

Comment: Either is possible, though "will" is redundant here since futurity is conveyed by the present tense together with the temporal adjunct "in September". Incidentally, using "will" does not make it future tense, since English does not actually have a future tense.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker (UK), I would say that both are correct. The word 'will' is not required in the sentence, but it is not a mistake to use it here. The difference (to me) is emphasis.